# Заполнить пропущенные строки

Tags: sql, sql-server

Имеется таблица с множеством id, где в значении даты стоит последняя дата месяца. значения не повторяются для каждого id. По типу:

| id | Дата | Цена |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 31.01.20 | 100 |
| 1 | 31.03.20 | 200 |
| 1 | 31.05.20 | 300 |

Есть ли какая какая-то возможность для каждого id заполнить пропущенные даты, чтобы на выходе получилось:

| id | Дата | Цена |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 31.01.20 | 100 |
| 1 | 28.02.20 | NULL |
| 1 | 31.03.20 | 200 |
| 1 | 30.04.20 | NULL |
| 1 | 31.05.20 | 300 |

Comment: уточните что вы хотите? физически заполнить таблицу NULL или вам нужен SQL запрос SELECT на формирование таблицы с NULL для работы с ней.

Comment: @SAnton запрос на формирование таблицы, чтобы в последствии с ней работать.

Comment: Тут несколько вариантов есть, можно LEFT JOIN сделать по таблице с нужными датами, только даты надо тоже генерить SQL запросом (это общий запрос для различных SQL), чтобы не ошибиться с февралем в високосном году. Какой используете MySQL, postgreSQL или еще какой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Набираем массив дат рекурсивным запросом, к нему добавляем таблицу с ценами:

```
declare @DateStart smalldatetime
       ,@DateEnd   smalldatetime

if object_id('tempdb..#Data') is not null drop table #Data
   create table #Data (id int, date smalldatetime, Price int)

insert #Data values (1,'20211231',100),(1,'20220531',100),(1,'20220731',100)


select @DateStart = min(Date), @DateEnd   = max(Date)
from #Data

    ;WITH Dates AS
    (
        SELECT @DateStart AS DateStart
        UNION ALL

        SELECT DATEADD(mm, 1, DateStart) AS DateStart
        FROM Dates
        WHERE eomonth(DateStart) < @DateEnd
    )
    select d.id, eomonth(dt.DateStart), Price
      from Dates dt
      left join #Data d on d.date = eomonth(dt.DateStart)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Если не рассматривать случай, когда перерыв между датами не очень большой, можно так

```
select id
  ,case when n=1 or n is null then PriceDate
   else eomonth(dateadd(mm,n-1,Pricedate))
   end PriceDate
  ,case when n=1 or n is null then Price
   else null
  end Price
from (select * 
        ,lead(PriceDate,1,PriceDate)over(partition by id order by PriceDate) nextDt
      from test
     ) t 
left join (select 1 n union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4
    union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8
    union all select 9 union all select 10 union all select 11 union all select 12
    union all select 13 union all select 14 union all select 15 union all select 16
   ) ds
 on n<=datediff(mm,PriceDate,nextDt)
```

Здесь генерация последовательности простым способом. Функция eomonth есть в SQL server. В других, возможно, придется заморочиться.